# Jenkins setup on EC2 vs ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, devops, amazon-ecs

Currently we have Jenkins that is running on-premise(VMware), planning to move into the cloud(aws). What would be the best approach to install Jenkins whether on ec2 or ECS?

Answer (score 2):

Best way would be running on EC2. Make sure you have granular control over your instance Security Group and Network ACL's. I would recommend using terraform to build your environment as you can write code and also version control it. https://www.terraform.io/downloads.html

Comment: @saurabh14292 made a good point there. You could containerise your jenkins locally and test. I would mainly prefer EC2 over ECS in cases of jenkins but its completely up to you.

Answer (score 2):

Have you previously containerized your Jenkins? On VMWare itself? If not, and if you are not having experience with containers, go for EC2. It will be as easy as running on any other VM. For reproducing the infrastructure, use Terraform or CloudFormartion.

I would recommend dockerize your on-premise Jenkins first. See how much efforts are required in implementation and administrating/scaling it. Then go for ECS.

Else, shift to EC2 and see how much admin overhead + costs you are billed. Then if required, go for ECS.

Another point you have to consider is how your Jenkins is architected. Are you using master-slave? Are you running builds contentiously so that VMs are never idle? Do you want easy scaling such that build environment is created and destroyed per build execution?

Comment: No we haven’t containerized any of our current Jenkins setup. I have some understanding of containers, but not in real-time experience. Currently we’re using master-slave architecture with one master and 6 slaves which are sitting idle for almost 12 hours a day. Yes, looking to implement on-demand slaves either using AMIs or docker images

Comment: I suggest to create a custom AMI to serve as Build Environment from Jenkins Slave. You can trigger an EC2 from it and attach to Jenkins master in automated way, and destroy the slave once build is done.
You can put the slaves behind AutoScalingGroup to scale up/down as per needs.

Have a look at this blog:
https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-deploy-a-jenkins-cluster-on-aws-as-part-of

Answer (score 1):

If you have no experience with running containers then create it on EC2. Before running on ECS make sure you really understand containers and container orchestration.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to complement the other answers by providing link to official AWS white paper:

- [Jenkins on AWS](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/DevOps/Jenkins_on_AWS.pdf)

It might be of special interest as it discusses both options in detail: EC2 and ECS:

> In this section we discuss **two approaches** to deploying Jenkinson AWS. First, you could use the traditional deployment on top of Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon **EC2**). Second, you could use the containerized deployment that leverages Amazon EC2 Container Service (Amazon **ECS**).Both approaches are **production-ready for an enterprise environment**.

There is also  AWS sample solution for Jenkins on AWS for ECS:

- https://github.com/aws-samples/jenkins-on-aws:

> This project will build and deploy an **immutable, fault tolerant, and cost effective Jenkins environment in AWS using ECS**. All Jenkins images are managed within the repository (pulled from upstream) and fully configurable as code. Plugin installation is automated, including versioning, as well as configured through the Configuration as Code plugin.